# Calling InterlockedAdd on RWByteAddressBuffer multiple times gives unexpected results (on NVidia)

Tags: directx, nvidia, directx-11, hlsl

I was looking to move back from using counter buffer for some compute shader routines, and had some unexpected behaviour on Nvidia cards

I made a really simplified example (so it does not make sense to do that, but that's the smallest that can reproduce the issue I encounter).

So I want to perform conditional writes in several locations on a buffer (also for simplification, I only run a single thread, since the behaviour can also be reproduced that way).

I will write 4 uints, then 2 uint3 (using InterlockedAdd to "simulate conditional writes")

So I use a single buffer (with raw access on uav), with the following simple layout :

```
0 -> First counter
4 -> Second counter
8 till 24 -> First 4 ints to write
24 till 48 -> Pair of uint3 to write
```

I also clear the buffer every frame (0 for each counter, and arbitrary value for the rest, 12345 in this case).

I copy the buffer staging resource in order to check the values, so yes my pipeline binding is correct, but I can post the code if asked for.

Now when I call the compute shader, only performing 4 increments as here :

```
RWByteAddressBuffer RWByteBuffer : BACKBUFFER;

#define COUNTER0_LOCATION 0
#define COUNTER1_LOCATION 4
#define PASS1_LOCATION 8
#define PASS2_LOCATION 24

[numthreads(1,1,1)]
void CS(uint3 tid : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{   
    uint i0,i1,i2,i3;
    RWByteBuffer.InterlockedAdd(COUNTER0_LOCATION, 1, i0);
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i0 * 4, 10);

    RWByteBuffer.InterlockedAdd(COUNTER0_LOCATION, 1, i1);
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i1 * 4, 20);

    RWByteBuffer.InterlockedAdd(COUNTER0_LOCATION, 1, i2);
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i2 * 4, 30);

    RWByteBuffer.InterlockedAdd(COUNTER0_LOCATION, 1, i3);
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i3 * 4, 40);
}
```

I then obtain the following results (formatted a little):

```
4,0,
10,20,30,40,
12345,12345,12345,12345,12345,12345,12345,12345,12345
```

Which is correct (counter is 4 as I called 4 times, second one was not called), I get 10 till 40 in the right locations, and rest has default values

Now if I want to reuse those indices in order to write them to another location:

```
[numthreads(1,1,1)]
void CS(uint3 tid : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    uint i0,i1,i2,i3;
    RWByteBuffer.InterlockedAdd(COUNTER0_LOCATION, 1, i0);
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i0 * 4, 10);

    RWByteBuffer.InterlockedAdd(COUNTER0_LOCATION, 1, i1);
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i1 * 4, 20);

    RWByteBuffer.InterlockedAdd(COUNTER0_LOCATION, 1, i2);
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i2 * 4, 30);

    RWByteBuffer.InterlockedAdd(COUNTER0_LOCATION, 1, i3);
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i3 * 4, 40);

    uint3 inds = uint3(i0, i1, i2);
    uint3 inds2 = uint3(i1,i2,i3);

    uint writeIndex;
    RWByteBuffer.InterlockedAdd(COUNTER1_LOCATION, 1, writeIndex);
    RWByteBuffer.Store3(PASS2_LOCATION + writeIndex * 12, inds);

    RWByteBuffer.InterlockedAdd(COUNTER1_LOCATION, 1, writeIndex);
    RWByteBuffer.Store3(PASS2_LOCATION + writeIndex * 12, inds2);
}
```

Now If I run that code on Intel card (tried HD4000 and HD4600), or ATI card 290, I get expected results eg :

```
4,2,
10,20,30,40,
0,1,2,1,2,3
```

But running that on NVidia (used 970m, gtx1080, gtx570) , I get the following :

```
4,2,
40,12345,12345,12345,
0,0,0,0,0,0
```

So it seems it suddenly returns 0 in the return value of interlocked add (it still increments properly as counter is 4, but we end up with 40 in last value.
Also we can see that only 0 got written in i1,i2,i3

In case I "reserve memory", eg, call Interlocked only once per location (incrementing by 4 and 2 , respectively):

```
[numthreads(1,1,1)]
void CSB(uint3 tid : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    uint i0;
    RWByteBuffer.InterlockedAdd(COUNTER0_LOCATION, 4, i0);
    uint i1 = i0 + 1;
    uint i2 = i0 + 2;
    uint i3 = i0 + 3;
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i0 * 4, 10);
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i1 * 4, 20);
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i2 * 4, 30);
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i3 * 4, 40);

    uint3 inds = uint3(i0, i1, i2);
    uint3 inds2 = uint3(i1,i2,i3);

    uint writeIndex;
    RWByteBuffer.InterlockedAdd(COUNTER1_LOCATION, 2, writeIndex);
    uint writeIndex2 = writeIndex + 1;
    RWByteBuffer.Store3(PASS2_LOCATION + writeIndex * 12, inds);
    RWByteBuffer.Store3(PASS2_LOCATION + writeIndex2 * 12, inds2);
}
```

Then this works on all cards, but I have some cases when I have to rely on the earlier behaviour.

As a side note, if I use structured buffers with a counter flag on the uav instead of a location in a byte address and do :

```
RWStructuredBuffer<uint> rwCounterBuffer1;
RWStructuredBuffer<uint> rwCounterBuffer2;

RWByteAddressBuffer RWByteBuffer : BACKBUFFER;

#define PASS1_LOCATION 8
#define PASS2_LOCATION 24

[numthreads(1,1,1)]
void CS(uint3 tid : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    uint i0 = rwCounterBuffer1.IncrementCounter();
    uint i1 = rwCounterBuffer1.IncrementCounter();
    uint i2 = rwCounterBuffer1.IncrementCounter();
    uint i3 = rwCounterBuffer1.IncrementCounter();

    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i0 * 4, 10);
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i1 * 4, 20);
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i2 * 4, 30);
    RWByteBuffer.Store(PASS1_LOCATION + i3 * 4, 40);

    uint3 inds = uint3(i0, i1, i2);
    uint3 inds2 = uint3(i1,i2,i3);

    uint writeIndex1= rwCounterBuffer2.IncrementCounter();
    uint writeIndex2= rwCounterBuffer2.IncrementCounter();

    RWByteBuffer.Store3(PASS2_LOCATION + writeIndex1* 12, inds);
    RWByteBuffer.Store3(PASS2_LOCATION + writeIndex2* 12, inds2);
```

}

This works correctly across all cards, but has all sorts of issues (that are out of topic for this question).

This is running on DirectX11 (I did not try it on DX12, and that's not relevant to my use case, except plain curiosity)

So is it a bug on NVidia? 
Or is there something wrong with the first approach?